# How to show the date/time two hours from current time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date-arithmetic

I'd like to show the date/time, two hours after the current time.

```
DateTime value = DateTime.Now;
DateTime newvalue = value.AddHours(2);
label5.Text = ???
```

Comment: `label5.Text = newValue;`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this seems to be what you want:

```
label5.Text = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2).ToString("dd/MM/yyyyy hh:mm"); // or whatever format you like
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do but you've already added 2 hours to newvalue. You just need to add it to the textbox now, using:

```
textBox_NameOfTextBox.Text = newvalue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

label5.Text = newvalue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

yes, add date format.